# JavaScript settimeout in Qt WebKit

Tags: javascript, webkit, settimeout

I’m using qt webkit to get page’s content. In my program, I catch two signals,  QWebFrame’s `loadFinished` and `initialLayoutCompleted`, when both signal is received, I’m output the page’s content. But it’s can’t process this page(I need to get  google’s content):

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    setTimeout('window.document.location.href="http://www.google.com";',2000
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

This page redirect to www.google.com after 2 sec, so , when I get `loadFinished`  and `initialLayoutCompleted` signal,  I get nothing output. 
So, I want to execute the javascript timing events(redirect to google) immediately ，not to wait 2 sec. Is there any way to do this? 
Apologize for my poor english!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, all you need to do is change the "2000" into a different number, for example

```
setTimeout('window.document.location.href="http://www.google.com"',2000);
```

Or, you can remove the timeout altogether:

```
window.document.location.href="http://www.google.com"
```

and it will go immediately, without setting a timeout.

Comment: I don't want to modify the page's html code,and in my program ,i execute javascript automatic:settings->setAttribute(QWebSettings::JavascriptEnabled, true); so,what i want to know is whether  Qt hava a method to  forbid this kind of javascript timing event.

Comment: For that, can't help you, sorry. :(